# springjdbc with preparedstatement

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

While running `spring jdbc`, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
```

Comment: No one will be able to help you unless you post the code that generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "/**/combined2.xml", "/**/xxx.xml"});

Comment: package com.javatpoint;  
  
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;  
public class Test {  
  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");  
          
    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)ctx.getBean("edao");  
    dao.saveEmployeeByPreparedStatement(new Employee(108,"Amit",35000));  
}  
}